# ActiveMQ scheduler jobs count

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx

I have activemq 5.15.* with jolokia getting for jmx status + python.

With this code i can get all scheduled jobs

```
j4p.request(type = 'read', mbean = '*:brockerName=*:name=JMS:service=JobSheduler:type=Broker')
```

If number of jobs too big request running too long with http timeout.

But I no need all jobs only they count, there is any way get only jobs count?

Answer (score 1):

Because if the architecture of the on disk storage for the Job Scheduler there is no in memory job count that is kept as the in memory index holds on a cached subset of the total jobs and you don't always have an accurate view of what is on disk (especially after broker restart) so the management interface only exposes access to fetch jobs not to fetch statistics in general.  To load and collect the numbers you'd generally be doing just what the code does now and then only exposing a fixed numeric result following all the hard work.

You could extend the store interface and carefully add such features if you wanted, the source code is open.  You'd need to properly test that it works both during normal operation and after restart or after some cached data is paged out.  The project is always looking for contributors.